# Generating a Rails form with dynamically-generated fields that submits data to a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, join, many-to-many, simple-form

I have a spreadsheet that I want to convert into Rails. The spreadsheet looks like this:

```
             | UserA | UserB | UserC | . . . .
Criterium 1
Criterium 2
 . . .
Criterium n
```

I’d like to be able to create a Rails form to mimic the function of the spreadsheet. The problem is that I don’t know how many users there will be and I’d like to have them dynamically added, ideally through its own table. But how do I create the form with this dynamically added information?

At the moment, I am using a simple many-to-many database model as follows (though I’m not sure if this is the best way to do this):

```
class Criterium < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :criteria_rankings
   has_many :users, :through => :criteria_rankings
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :criteria_rankings
   has_many :criteria, :through => :criteria_rankings
end

class CriteriaRanking < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :criterium
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Ideally, I would be able to use the Criterium model to generate a form that, when submitted, creates multiple records in the CriteriaRanking model, but only one per user. Imagine a form such as this:

```
Criterium 1:  

User A Ranking    |_____|  

User B Ranking    |_____|  
 . . . .  
User n Ranking    |_____|
```

So, if there are *n* users, then there will be *n* fields in the form. Each form field, however, will correspond to a field in the CriteriaRanking join table. How can I generate the form to not only present the fields in this fashion but then to ***record*** the values in the CriteriaRanking join table, with each record containing the correct User ID?

FWIW I'm using SimpleForm.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Thanks, Jason. It's valuable info but doesn't quite match with what I'm trying to do. Ryan did not use a many-to-many DB example so I'm having trouble understanding how to apply his approach with my situation.

Comment: Also, I edited the description of the question so hopefully it'll be a bit clearer what I'm trying to accomplish.